# Uninstalled Windows 10 Driver Cannot Get Internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers

I need help. I've uninstalled all the network drivers on a Dell XPS 15 9550 Signature Edition. The internet was hardly working at all and one of the tutorials suggested reinstalling. Problem is: once you uninstall the network driver the computer cannot get internet. It also doesn't have an ethernet... What do I do? I was thinking of possibly downloading the network driver on a different computer and linking it but I'm not sure?

Comment: You need a different computer and a USB drive.

Comment: Why the down votes? I feel I can justify why this question is a good one. You have to uninstall the network drivers to get WIFI working well on a Windows 10 computer. But, this particular laptop had no ethernet drive. Not to mention you cannot easily find what driver you need for the wireless card once it is uninstalled because the computer doesn't know what it is at that point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution is to use the phone as a wireless hot spot. Therefore the Iphone or whatever smartphone you have acts as a wireless card. Then you go to device manager and find the unidentified hardware, right click and search for drivers using the internet on your phone.

Answer (score 2):

As "spherical_dog" mentioned above, the only sensible way to do this is to find another computer with internet, download the driver installer onto a usb drive, and run it on the faulty machine - that should easily fix the issue.

Do make sure it's the right driver though, it'll save a lot of head scratching...